# I want to change a horizontal list view to select box in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a simple ul li list as below:

```
<ul>
    <li>All</li>
    <li>All</li>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

I want this to be like select box in mobile devices

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (the JavaScript code using jQuery), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Comment: create as elect box and hide it initially. and at the mobile width open it and hide your horizontal menu

Answer (score 1):

```
hello friend,

if you need your <ul> <li> structure as select box in mobile device,so you need to  code this structure twice.

1. as you already write.add class name to hide this in mobile
<ul class="list-desktop-wrap">
    <li>All</li>
    <li>All</li>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
</ul>



2.<div class="section-mobile-only">
<select>
  <option value="All" selected>All</option>
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option3">Option 3</option>
</select>  
</div>
As make this section display none in desktop & and display block in mobile device. if you need to view select box after 768 resolution (i-pad) so make css as 
@media (max-width:768px){
.list-desktop-wrap{display:none};
 .section-mobile-only{display:block};
}

initally its 

.section-mobile-only{display:none};
```